# Error AutoFixture CreateMany Method

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am writing a Unit Test using Microsot Nunit and Autofixture. I am getting a problem that When I generate a objects through AutoFixture and try to iterate over them, It does not produce result and hold on to that line. I tried to Debug it but same thing happen. When it comes to iteration, it does hold on to that place. Please find my code below.

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Behaviors.Remove(new ThrowingRecursionBehavior());
fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());
fixture.Customizations.Add(new XsdRestrictionHandler());
fixture.Customize(new MultipleCustomization());
foreach(var invoice in fixture.Build<ReceiptInvoice>().CreateMany(100))
{    
}
```

As I mentioned It does not iterate over element and hold onto that place and even does not produce any error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What value is ´number´?

Comment: number means how many object autofixture needs to create. For example I set in my code 100.

Comment: What do you mean that *it does not iterate over element and hold onto that place?* Also, which version of AutoFixture are you using?